# Link text doesn't disapear when hovered on

Tags: css

I have a set of  boxes with background images on them and have centred with text in them. When you hover on the box the image zoom and animation is working as it should, but the text is only disappears when you hover directly on it not the box itself.

[**My Code**](http://codepen.io/liga/pen/e1c396a89a1870069df2713450f0b07b?editors=1100)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(236, 237, 229);
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

.parent {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 430px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 20px 60px 20px;
}

.child {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all .5s;
  display: flex;
}

.child a {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .4em;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid;
  text-shadow: 2px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  padding: 5px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.child a:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.child:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child bg_boats">
      <a href="#">Boats</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child bg_hats">
      <a href="#">Hats</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child bg_coffeeflowers">
      <a href="#">Coffee & flowers</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child bg_crystals">
      <a href="#">Crystals</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I am new to programming and the only solution that I came to was to make *.child a* an inline-block element and then take the border off and apply the padding. However that looked messy and the text was displayed wrongly.

Comment: What is expected? For the text to disappear when you hover over any part of the box?

Comment: whay do you want ? if hover box then display box ?

Comment: Yes,  I wanted for the text disappear when the box is hovered. The answer by Jordan S helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.child:hover a {
   opacity: 0;
}
```

If you want to text to disappear when you hover over the box, change your selector to `.child:hover a`. This selects any `<a>` tag within a `.child` element that is being hovered over.

[Adjusted behavior.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WpGmJE?editors=1100)

Answer (score -1):

You have to make

```
.child a:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```